# Recording Products Ordered

Tags: java

So my first problem has been fixed here: [CLICK HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155856/scanner-input-not-reading-method-calling-as-a-parameter/7155877#7155877)
Thanks to seanA for the quick response...

My Second Problem now is I don't know how to record the Data the Buyer has ordered
so in the Final Order Display it will show something like this:
[CLICK TO VIEW](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/1483/orderinformation.jpg)

here's the updated code of the class PointofSale
Suggest an Addition Method or anything if needed :) Thanks in advance

```
import java.util.*;
public class PointOfSale extends ProductDisplay
{   public double amount; public double total;
    public PointOfSale()
    {   System.out.print("\nPurchase Item(y/n)?:\t\t");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        if("y".equalsIgnoreCase(line)){
        OpenOrder();
            }
    }
    //=============================================
    public void OpenOrder() // New Order
    {   ArrayList<String> ProductList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ProductList.add("A001");    ProductList.add("A002");
        ProductList.add("A003");    ProductList.add("A004");
        ProductList.add("A005");
        System.out.print("Enter Product Code:\t\t");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String code = sc.next();
        if(ProductList.contains(code))
        { product.getProduct(code); EnterQuantity();        }
        else System.out.print("Product Code is Invalid\n"); System.exit(0);}
    //==============================================
    public void EnterQuantity()  //Entering Quantity
    {
        try{
            System.out.print("Enter Quantity:\t\t\t");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int quantity = sc.nextInt();
            amount = quantity * product.getPrice();
            total = total + amount;
            System.out.print("Amount:\t\t\t\t\t" + amount + "\n");
            AddItem(); }
        catch (InputMismatchException nfe)
            {System.out.print("\nInvalid Entry: Input must be a Number.\n"); System.exit(0);}
    }
    //==============================================
    public void AddItem()  //Adding Item
    {
        try{
            System.out.print("Add More Item(y/n)?:\t\t\t");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String item = sc.next();
            if("y".equalsIgnoreCase(item)){
            OpenOrder();}
            else if("n".equalsIgnoreCase(item)){
            System.out.print("Total:\t\t" + total + "\n");}
            }
        catch (InputMismatchException nfe)
            {System.out.print("\nInvalid Entry: Input must be a Number.\n"); System.exit(0);}
    }
    // Main Method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   new PointOfSale(); }
}
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt to solve this? If so where? If not, you should decompose the problem into smaller steps and try to solve each step one at a time. A useful reference that can help with this step is [So, You Need to Write a Program but Don't Know How to Start](http://home.earthlink.net/~patricia_shanahan/beginner.html) by Patricia Shanahan. *Then* if you get stuck, you can come back and ask a much more specific and answerable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to store the data that you entered in array or use java.util.Vector.

the use the for loop to display it in the form that you want

I hope it helps.

:)

Comment: can you do me an example of how i can use vector in this class?

Comment: Glad you got teh codez. Hope you have *the understanding*. :)